# How to select only specific unique values from a range of columns which are associated with an ID in another column using R

Tags: r

```
ID conditionA conditionB conditionC
1    1            0       0
1    0            0       1
1    0            0       0
2    1            0       1
2    0            1       0
3    1            0       1
3    0            1       0
3    1            1       0
```

in the picture above, I want for each ID only single value of each condition, making it a single row for each ID. This way I can have one row for each ID and under each condition a 1 or 0. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This can be easily done by using the dplyr package.

```
library(dplyr)

data %>%
  group_by(ID) %>%
  summarize(
    conditionA = max(conditionA), 
    conditionB = max(conditionB),
    conditionC = max(conditionC)
  )
```

The `group_by()` will group by `ID`, then the `summarize()` fnction will coalesce all rows under that `ID` to a single one. `conditionA` will assume the maximum value found in all rows for that ID, that is, if a 1 is present, then it will be one; if only 0s are present, then the maximum will be zero. Same for `conditionB`, and `conditionC`.

Comment: A similar approach in base R could be `aggregate(. ~ ID, data, max)`

Comment: These are both great answers and works. However, in my data I have some factor columns as well.What if I want the max on a range of columns but also want the rest of the columns in the results? i.e, max on the numeric columns but get the rest of the columns as well. Thanks

Comment: I think if I add the other columns which are dates and factors in the group_by and then use the summarise and max on the rest of numeric columns it works as well.